# How to use a JSON ENCODED data to Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some pages on the web which echo results like:

```
[{"id":"1","company":"Gaurishankar","bus_no":"JHA 12 KH 1230"},
{"id":"2","company":"Gaurishankar","bus_no":"BA 2 KH 2270"}]
```

I want to use this json_encode data to be used in Javascript array like:

```
var data = http://api.mywebsite.com/get_data.php;
for (i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
//Do something here
}
```

How is this possible. I know its easy but I cant make this. I am a new learner. Plz help

Comment: Someone needs to read up on [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), it's as simple as:

```
$.get( "http://api.mywebsite.com/get_data.php", function( data ) {
    for (i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
        alert(data[i].id);
    }
});
```